# ASP.NET Displaying Date in Label

Tags: asp.net, datetime-format

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Displays

```
03.06.2014 10:30:00
```

How can I display it as `3 Jun 2014 10:30`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should work:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Eval("Date", "{0:d MMM yyyy HH:mm}") %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

See: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Simplest one. Thanks.

Comment: @tim I have this markup `<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Eval("Date", "{0:d 'de' MMM 'de' yyyy") %>'>
</asp:Label>` but the scape characters inside the format string are giving me error. How can I scape the scape characters?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Text='<%# Eval("Date", "{d MMM yyyy hh:mm}") %>'
```

You can see more format strings [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/).

Comment: Input string was not in correct format. I suppose Eval instead of Bind.

Comment: @Jude, updated - sorry I assumed you were in a DataGrid or similar

Comment: No worries, yours was going to be accepted. Sorry I went for Tim's.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Bind("Date").ToString("d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")) %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

ref: [Custom date time formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#Y100)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
Bind("Date").ToString("d MMM yyyy hh:mm")
```

You could also do this:

```
string.Format("{0:d MMM yyyy hh:mm}",Bind("Date"))
```

Comment: @Jude: this doesn't work because `Bind("Date")` returns an object not a `DateTime`, an object has no `ToString` with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

this would display

> ```
> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
>            Text='<%# ((DateTime)Bind("Date")).ToString("f", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")) %>'></asp:Label>
> ```

Comment: Wouldn't the "f" just display the fraction of the second?

Comment: you can find it more about that here; [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#FullDateShortTime)